# Best practice to avoid side effects

Tags: java, multithreading, jakarta-ee, thread-safety

I have a question about how to avoid side effects on Java objects. 
Let us suppose I have an instance **myObject** of the class **MyObject**. I would like to process **myobject** through a chain of methods/commands and at each command level, I want to enrich **myObject** with what the method/command has computed.

Here the class which **myObject** is an instance of:

```
public class MyObject {
  private int resultOfCommand1;
  private int resultOfCommand2;
  private int resultOfCommand3;
  private int resultOfCommand4;
  ....
  ....
}
```

Here are the methods/commands which **myObject** has to be processed through:

```
private MyObject command1(MyObject myObject) {
   return myObject.setRresultOfCommand1(1);
}
private MyObject command2(MyObject myObject) {
   return myObject.setRresultOfCommand2(2);
}
private MyObject command3(MyObject myObject) {
   return myObject.setRresultOfCommand3(3);
}
private MyObject command4(MyObject myObject) {
   return myObject.setRresultOfCommand4(4);
}
```

So the design shown above does have side-effects and I would like to avoid such a thing.

Could anybody tell me the best way to avoid side effects? Is it better to always make of copy of the object that was passed as a parameter (in this case myObject), do the changes on the copy and then return it?
Is there a best way that guarantee multi-thread-safeness?

Any Help would be appreciated.
Horace

Comment: What you have done just looks like overcomplicated getters and setters...and then since you mention threads..use synchronized

Comment: Have you looked into making it a pipeline pattern? Pass the object through an array of command classes with each modifying the object. Only if there is no meat in each of the commands being processed, then it becomes too fragmented. On the plus side, the commands to be executed can be easily varied. Look at an implementation of this pattern in netty, http://docs.jboss.org/netty/3.2/api/org/jboss/netty/channel/ChannelPipeline.html

Answer (score 2):

If you want to avoid side effects, the methods which set a value must not alter the instance, instead they return a new instance (a copy). Within that method, you use a constructor to set all (final) values.

Example:

```
class C {
    private final int x;
    private final int y;

    public C(int _x) {
        super();
        this.x = _x;
        this.y = -1;
    }

    public C(int _x, int _y) {
        super();
        this.x = _x;
        this.y = _y;
    }

    public C setY(int _y) {
        return new C(this.x, _y);
    }
}
```

To prevent side effects, just declare the fields as `final`. If all fields are `final`, the values (in case of primitive types) and object references are immutable. In case of an object reference, that object must be immutable as well to achieve "complete immutability".

So you do not change the copy, but you *construct* a copy with the new values.

Now it's safe to pass the immutable instance around; it cannot change, so it's thread-safe.